# Need loop help for building table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html-table

Here is my function:

```
function CreateResultsTable(bps, incs) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var str = '<table border=1>';
    str += '<tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th></tr>';

    var i = 0;

    // up
    for (i = 0; i < incs; i++) {
        var num = (incs - i) * bps;
        var newStr = num.toString();
        str += '<tr><th>' + newStr + '</th><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td></tr>';
    }
    i = 0;

    //down
    for (i = incs; i > 0; i--) {
        var num = (incs - i) * bps;
        var newStr = '-' + num.toString();
        str += '<tr><th>' + newStr + '</th><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td></tr>';
    }
    return str;
}
```

What I want is say I pass in `{bps = 25, incs = 4}`. It should always create double the amount of rows (underneath the header row) of incs. So for incs = `4` and bps = `25`, it should create rows with first td = `100, 75, 50, 25, -25, -50, -75, -100` -- in that order.

What it's doing now is creating them like `100, 75, 50, 25, -0, -25, -50` -- and that's it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't forget to close your `table` element.

Comment: Don't try to build the insides of tables with strings. Use createElement and friends. IE really doesn't like changing the innerHTML of bits of tables.

Comment: @David - What you said is true, but he's not doing that, he's creating an entire table, so while I don't prefer it either...it's not an issue in IE.

Comment: Argh. I looked at line two and didn't notice that the result is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start at `incs -1` and to count to zero. So the function should look like

```
function CreateResultsTable(bps, incs) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        var str = '<table border=1>';
        str += '<tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th></tr>';

        var i = 0;

        // up
        for (i = 0; i < incs; i++) {
            var num = (incs - i) * bps;
            var newStr = num.toString();
            str += '<tr><th>' + newStr + '</th><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td></tr>';
        }
        i = 0;

        //down
        for (i = incs - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var num = (incs - i) * bps;
            var newStr = '-' + num.toString();
            str += '<tr><th>' + newStr + '</th><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td></tr>';
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: While this does solve the issue in the question, there's a *much* simpler way to go about it, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

You last loop needs to be `>=` instead of just `>` and start one lower, like this:

```
for (i = incs-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZN3tD/2/), the only other change is a `</table>` addition at the end and quotes on your border attribute.

---

There is a much simpler way to go about this though, use a single loop and exclude `0` if you want, like this:

```
function CreateResultsTable(bps, incs) {
    var str = '<table border="1">';
    str += '<tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th></tr>';

    for (var i = incs*bps, low = -i; i >= low; i-=bps) {
        if (i == 0) continue; //exclude the 0 row
        str += '<tr><th>' + i + '</th><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td><td>100,000</td></tr>';
    }
    str += '</table>';
    return str;
}
```

[You can test the result here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZN3tD/4/), it's just a simpler/cheaper single-loop way or doing the same thing.

Comment: So he'll get `100, 75, 50, 25, -0, -25, -50 100` and not `100, 75, 50, 25, -25, -50 100`.

Comment: @gregor - woops you're right, I mis-read his *expected* result from the question (mixed it with his actual when reading), answer/demo updated.